# Save data from textbox after user selected 'others' option in a drop down box

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a drop down list where the user will select return reason. the drop down has 'other' option which will display another textbox to insert another info. I already got the code to save value from drop down but not the value in the textbox if user selects 'other' option. thanks!

Here is my drop down:

```
<td width="218">
  <select name="returnreason" id="returnreason"  onChange="others(this.value);">
    <option value="0"> --Select Return Reason-- </option>
    <option value="1">Damaged in transit</option>
    <option value="2">Wrong item delivered</option>
    <option value="3">Wrong item ordered</option>
    <option value="4">Demo/Service Unit</option>
    <option value="5">W/out warranty sticker</option>
    <option value="6">Does not work/broken (DOA)</option>
    <option value="7">Clients are not satisfied</option>
    <option value="8">Others</option>
  </select>
</td>

<div id="8" style="display:none;">
  Please specify <input type="text" id="8" name="8" class="forinput"/>
</div>
```

My js:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#returnplus").hide();        
    $("#addreturn").click(function() { 
      $("#returnplus").show("slow");
    });
  }
</script>
```

Here's for saving to the db:

```
$returnreason=isset($_POST['returnreason'])? $_POST['returnreason'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
$r8 = isset($_POST['8'])? $_POST['8'] : '';

if( $returnreason == 8 ){
    $returnreason_specify = $r8;
}
```

I don't understand what you realy want ...

If you just want your input '8' data its `$r8 = isset($_POST['8'])? $_POST['8'] : '';`